# small problem in css background

Tags: css

i want make two icons together side by side

My html code

```
<head>
<style>
.icon_one{
    width:25px;
    height: 20px;
    background:#ffffff url('icon_one.jpg') no-repeat right top;
}

.icon_two{
    width:25px;
    height: 20px;
    background:#ffffff url('icon_two.jpg') no-repeat right top;
}
</style>
</head>

<div class="icons"><div class="icon_one"></div><div class="icon_two"></div></div>
```

i want show them side by side

example :

icone1|icone2

but the code output

icond1

icone2

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
.icon_one, .icon_two{display:inline-block;}
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/pqmtb/)**

Then you wont have to worry about clearing floats later.

Otherwise you can use floats,

```
.icon_one, .icon_two{float:left;}
```

**[Demo with floats](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/pqmtb/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add a float to your elements...

```
.icon_one, .icon_two {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `float:left` to each icon class so they float next to each other, dont forget to add some margin space in between.

Answer (score 0):

You can either `float:left;` each `div` or set each `div` to `display:inline-block;`

**So Example 1:**

```
.icon_one, .icon_two{
    width:25px;
    height: 20px;
    background:red url('icon_one.jpg') no-repeat right top;
    display:inline-block;
}

.icon_two{
     background:blue url('icon_two.jpg') no-repeat right top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/YESWV/1/

**NB: You can actually trim down your code, as above.**

*Also, I changed the `background-color` so it was easier to see the example.*

**Example 2:**

```
.icon_one, .icon_two{
    width:25px;
    height: 20px;
    background:red url('icon_one.jpg') no-repeat right top;
    float:left;
}

.icon_two{
    background:blue url('icon_two.jpg') no-repeat right top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/YESWV/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the div's to spans instead.

```
<div class="icons">
    <span class="icon_one"></span>
    <span class="icon_two"></span>
</div>
```